# How can I create different patterns for the same image in <canvas>

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

I have an image, and I want to show the same image multiple times in the canvas with different rotations. For that I use `context.rotate()` to rotate the image and `context.fill()` to draw it. To be able to show the image using `fill()`, I first need to use `createPattern()` method, as in:

```
context.save();
var altPattern = context.createPattern(image, "repeat");
context.fillStyle = altPattern;
context.restore();
```

My problem is that although I use `save()` and `restore()`, the last `createPattern()` I use affects the first `fillStyles` as well, and draws all the images in a single rotation. How can I create different patterns for the same image, while using `context.rotate()` to rotate it?

Calling `createPattern()` again and assigning it to a different variable doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it. You should use `context.beginPath()` when beginning to fill or stroke a new part in the canvas. I didn't use it at first, I just used `moveTo()` and moved the context around, calling `fill()s` everywhere. It looked like it was working, but with `createPattern()` this problem came out. So for your safety, always begin with `context.beginPath()` for every complex shape you decide to fill or stroke.